# How restart the Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF
I need CLEAN and START again the window SetPathCharger.xaml when the user clic on "Yes" the message box, the problem is the application send a error InvalidOperationException.

```
public void ExitProgram(string message)
{
    var restart = MessageBox.Show("Do you want do it again?", 
                                  "Question", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
                                  MessageBoxImage.Question).ToString(); 
    if (restart == "Yes")
    {
        _setPathCharger.ShowDialog();
    }
    if (restart == "No")
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }         
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Quick sidenote: you should really use `DialogResult` enum directly instead of casting it to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just create and show a new `SetPathCharger` window, instead of reusing the current one.  Something like:

```
_setPathCharger = new SetPathCharger();
_setPathCharger.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: that solutions is good, but have a problem, when start the new window the previous window remains open. I need that closed when start the new.

Comment: Call `_setPathCharger.Close();` first, then create a new one

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ExitProgram is in some outer scope and is triggered after closing _setPathCharger then I suppose you are trying to ShowDialog() a disposed object.

Try to:

```
_setPathCharger = new SetPathCharger();
_setPathCharger.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: that solutions is good, but have a problem, when start the new window the previous window remains open. I need that closed when start the new.